# compare multiple value in same document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My question was, how to find all title of the releases contains the artist name
Here is the 2 Documents for just an example:

```
`{"release" : {"title" : "DEF day",
            "artists" : {"artist" : {"role" : "1","name" : "DEF"}}}
    }

{   "release" : {"title" : "XYZ day",
             "artists" : {"artist" : {"role" : "1","name" : "KYC"}}}
    }`
```

when i run this following query:

```
`db.test.find({$where:
  "this.release.title.indexOf(this.release.artists.artist.name) > -1"
```

})`

I get the result "DEF day", so it works excellent!! 
BUT, once i run this query to my original data(same format like above) i get this:

```
`error: {
"$err" : "TypeError: Object 30 has no method 'indexOf'\n    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:1:49) near 'his.release.artists.a' ",
"code" : 16722
```

}`

My collection is big (8GB+).
Just looking at the above error, can anyone tell what may be the problem with the above query? your answer is appreciated. please.

Comment: can you run the following query and post its output? `find({ field: { $type: 16 } })`

Comment: @n9code
Originally this collection is about 20GB. i have a small sample of 300MB.
Also the 'releases' has many more fields other than title, artists. 

btw, with running your code with the 300MB sample here is the rusult:

`here is the result: Fetched 0 record(s) in 9646ms`

Comment: the following query giving me the all exact matching (releases and artist) names:

db.releases.find({$where:
  "this.release.title == this.release.artists.artist.name"
}) 

but i need titles which contains the artist name.

Comment: no answer from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the data itself. Somewhere you have a document, where the `title` field is not `String`, thus invoking `indexOf` on the whole data, on that particular document you get the error.

One thing you can do to solve this problem is first of all find that erroneous document. To do that you will need to run a simple query.

MongoDB has the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#type) operator, which matches fields by their type. And [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types) is the list of all available BSON types a MongoDB document field can have.

The id of `String` BSON type is **`2`**, thus you need all the documents that have type of `title` field not equal to **`2`**.

```
find({field: {$not: {$type: <BSON type>}}}))
```

After finding the document(s), you may fix or remove them.